# How can i get index from map using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks, jsx

i am using routers and hooks in my code,
So i have 2 components
"AddRoom"
"Homescreen"
Inside app i have addroom() arrow function, and hook called "rooms" that is sent to "AddRoom" component like so:

```
      <Router>
      <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/' component={() => { returnn <HomeScreen rooms={rooms} /> }} /> 
      <Route exact path='/AddRoom' component={() => { return <AddRoom add={addRoom} rooms={rooms} /> }} /
       </Switch>
      </Router>
```

The "addRoom" function:

```
      const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);

      const addRoom = (room, name, color) => {
    //I have tried to use here map to add index for array "rooms" it is not working//
        setRooms([...rooms, { room: room, name: name, color: color ,index:{index}}])}
```

I am trying to get index everytime i add a room to "rooms" array but it wont add it to my array i dont understand why, how can i do it?

And that is "AddRoom" component:

```
    import React, { Component, useState } from
    'react'
    import context from 'react- 
    bootstrappp/esm/AccordionContext';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import { useHistory } from "react-router- 
    dom";

    export default function AddRoom(props) {

    const [room, setRoom] = useState()
    const [name, setName] = useState()
    const [color, setColor] = useState('black')
    const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false)
    const [index, setIndex] = useState([]);
    const history = useHistory();


    const validInput = () => {//input validation
        if ((name == null) || ((room == 'Choose') || (room == null))) {//no name typed and no room chosen
            debugger
            window.alert('Please choose a room and enter at least one character in room name');
            return true;//if alert pops up
        }
        else {
            if (name.length > 5) {
                return false;//name is too long
            }
        }

    }

    const AddClick = () => {
        let result = validInput();
        let path = '/';
        if (result == true)//no name was typed and room was not selected
        {
            debugger
            history.push(path);
        }
        else {
            if (name.length > 5) {//name is too long
                setShowError(true)
            }
            else//all fields are correct, go back to home screen with ner room
            {
                setShowError(false)
                /*  {props.rooms.map((element, i) => { */
                props.add(room , name , color /*(setIndex(...index, { index: i })) */);
            }
            )} 
            history.push(path);
        }
    }








    return (
        <div className='container' >
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-sm-12 text-center' style={{ textAlign: 'center', position: "relative", top: "80px", }}>

                    <select onChange={(element) => { setRoom(element.target.value) }} name="room" id="room">
                        <option value="Choose">Choose your room</option>
                        <option value="Livingroom">Livingroom</option>
                        <option value="Kitchen">Kitchen</option>
                        <option value="Bedroom">Bedroom</option>
                        <option value="Bathroom">Bathroom</option>
                    </select>
                    <br /><br />
                    <input onChange={(element) => { setName(element.target.value) }} id="name" type="text" placeholder="Room Name"></input>
                    <div style={{ color: 'red', marginTop: '5', display: showError ? "block" : "none" }}>Room Name Is More Then 5 Character</div>
                    <br /><br />
                    <input onChange={(element) => { setColor(element.target.value) }} id="color" type="color" placeholder="Room Color"></input>
                    <br /><br />
                    <button onClick={AddClick}>Create Room</button>

                </div></div></div>
    )
}
```

before calling addRoom function:

```
rooms=[{}]
```

after calling function addRoom:

```
rooms=[{room:"Kitchen",name:"Kit",color:"red",index:0},{room:"Bathroom",name:"Bat",color:"green",index:1}...]
```

Comment: the index of what? what does index in this case mean?

Comment: It looks like you always add the new element to the end of the array. Wouldn't the index always be `rooms.length - 1`?

Comment: index of rooms , i want every time i add a room object to rooms array to be like this :[.../rooms,{room,name,color,index}] ,but to add index i want to do a map loop so it will se the index every time i add the room in function "addRoom"

Comment: @ElanHamburger umm no, it adds every time a new room so i dont have this issue , i have only an issue with index i want every object room to be with index like so: [{room1},{room2},...]

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite understanding what it is you're trying to do. Would you mind updating your question with an example of what `rooms` looks like before you call `addRoom` and what you would want it to look like after the call?

Comment: @ElanHamburger i edited my code would love for you to look again : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're trying to `map` your array of rooms and you'd like the index of each room in the array.

If all you want is to get the index of the room while you are `map`-ing the array, you can provide a second argument to the `map` function which will have the index passed to it.

```
rooms.map((room, index) => {
    // Do stuff...
});
```

Actually storing the index within the object is an anti-pattern since you have no way of guaranteeing that the stored index actually matches its index in the array. Any time you add or remove a room not at the end, you'd have to update all the rooms with their new indices. Plus, unless you're storing references to all of these rooms outside of the array, you have to have the index before you can access a room anyway.

But if that's still what you want to do, you can either:

1. Store the index as you add the room

```
// Room is being added at the end, so its index must be rooms.length
setRooms([...rooms, { ...room, index: rooms.length }]);
```

2. Update the indices after each addition

```
// This is basically the first part of my answer with extra steps
setRooms([...rooms, room].map((room, index) => ({ ...room, index: index })));
```

Comment: @AlenaIgorevna Happy to help! If this solved your problem, please [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to help others who view this question in the future.